# How to refer another row in row_iterator Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code

```
row_iterator = temp.iterrows()
for i, row in row_iterator:
    row['InterE'] = row['xs'] - (row['xs'] - row['InterS']) * exp(-row['ak1'])
    if row['InterE'][:-1] < 1:
        row['InterS'] = row['InterE'][:-1]
    else:
        row['InterS'] = row['InterE'][:-1] - row['InterE'][:-1] * row['xi'][:-1]
```

But it returns me the following error:

```
invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid iterating especially when you can vectorise the operation.

So

```
# calculate 'InterE' column for entire dataframe
temp['InterE'] = temp['xs'] - (temp['xs'] - temp['InterS']) * exp(-temp['ak1'])
# now for those values less than 1 assign the previous row value, this is what shift does
temp.loc[temp['InterE'] < 1, 'InterS'] = temp['InterE'].shift(-1)
# for the other condition perform the alternative calculation and assign
temp.loc[temp['InterE'] >=1, 'InterS'] = temp['InterE'].shift(-1) - (temp['InterE'].shift(-1) * temp['xi'].shift(-1))
```

let me know if this does what you want, if not then post the data and desired output